# optimize a window aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, optimization, window-functions

First, the query

```
SELECT
    tc.numreg,
    com.numdep,
    tc.numcom,
    tc.numiris,
    sum(tc.conso_climat_reel)/sum(sum(tc.conso_climat_reel)) OVER (PARTITION BY tc.numreg) AS ratio,
    tc.annee_ref,
    tc.achl,
    tc.catl,
    tc.napfue,
    tc.usage,
    tc.chfl,
    tc.typl,
    tc.type_equipement,
    tc.modele_equipement
  FROM residentiel.tc_conso tc
  INNER JOIN general.commune com ON (tc.annee_ref=com.annee_ref::INTEGER AND tc.numcom=com.numcom)
  WHERE tc.napfue='111' AND tc.numreg='74' AND tc.annee_ref=2010
  GROUP BY tc.numreg, com.numdep, tc.numcom, tc.annee_ref, tc.achl, tc.catl, tc.napfue, tc.usage,
    tc.chfl, tc.typl, tc.numiris, tc.type_equipement, tc.modele_equipement
```

The table :

```
Table « residentiel.tc_conso »
       Colonne       |  Type   | Modificateurs 
---------------------+---------+---------------
 numreg              | text    | 
 numcom              | text    | 
 conso_climat_reel   | numeric | 
 conso_climat_normal | numeric | 
 annee_ref           | integer | 
 achl                | text    | 
 catl                | text    | 
 napfue              | text    | 
 usage               | text    | 
 chfl                | text    | 
 typl                | text    | 
 napfue_entree       | text    | 
 numiris             | text    | 
 type_equipement     | text    | 
 modele_equipement   | text    | 
Index :
    "tc_conso_annee_ref_idx" btree (annee_ref)
    "tc_conso_napfue_idx" btree (napfue)
    "tc_conso_numcom_idx" btree (numcom)
    "tc_conso_numreg_idx" btree (numreg)
Contraintes de clés étrangères :
    "modele_equipement_fk" FOREIGN KEY (modele_equipement) REFERENCES residentiel.modele_equipement_bois(modele_equipement)
    "tc_conso_achl_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (achl) REFERENCES residentiel.achl_groupe(groupe)
    "tc_conso_catl_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (catl) REFERENCES residentiel.catl_groupe(groupe)
    "tc_conso_chfl_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (chfl) REFERENCES residentiel.chfl_groupe(groupe)
    "tc_conso_napfue_entree_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (napfue_entree) REFERENCES general.napfue(napfue)
    "tc_conso_napfue_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (napfue) REFERENCES general.napfue(napfue)
    "tc_conso_typl_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (typl) REFERENCES residentiel.typl_groupe(groupe)
    "tc_conso_usage_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (usage) REFERENCES residentiel.usage(usage)
    "type_equipement_fk" FOREIGN KEY (type_equipement) REFERENCES residentiel.type_equipement_bois(type_equipement)
```

The problem : For the purpose of this question the WHERE clause is set up for a single tuple of possibilities, but in reality this query lives inside a function loop. The function takes too long time to performs (more than 3h).
The query plan :

```
WindowAgg  (cost=343383.85..344148.09 rows=23515 width=77)
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=343383.85..343795.36 rows=23515 width=77)
        Group Key: tc.numreg, com.numdep, tc.numcom, tc.annee_ref, tc.achl, tc.catl, tc.napfue, tc.usage, tc.chfl, tc.typl, tc.numiris, tc.type_equipement, tc.modele_equipement
        ->  Merge Join  (cost=339208.00..341953.97 rows=38130 width=77)
              Merge Cond: ((com.numcom)::text = tc.numcom)
              ->  Sort  (cost=15124.34..15131.67 rows=2935 width=14)
                    Sort Key: com.numcom
                    ->  Seq Scan on commune com  (cost=0.00..14955.29 rows=2935 width=14)
                          Filter: ((annee_ref)::integer = 2010)
              ->  Sort  (cost=324083.14..325258.73 rows=470236 width=74)
                    Sort Key: tc.numcom
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tc_conso tc  (cost=35624.23..279779.79 rows=470236 width=74)
                          Recheck Cond: (numreg = ''74''::text)
                          Filter: ((annee_ref = 2010) AND (napfue = ''111''::text))
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tc_conso_numreg_idx  (cost=0.00..35506.67 rows=1922432 width=0)
                                Index Cond: (numreg = ''74''::text)
```

As I understand, the problem comes on the sort of the tc.numcom column, but there's already a index on it. So, how can I optimize the query?
Thanks

PS :
The function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION residentiel.create_tc_conso_corrigees()
  RETURNS VOID
AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    rec RECORD;
    rec2 RECORD;
    total_reg DOUBLE PRECISION;
    total_niv DOUBLE PRECISION;
    res_snap CONSTANT TEXT := '020200';
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'Vidage de la table tc_conso_corrigees...';
  TRUNCATE TABLE residentiel.tc_conso_corrigees;

  FOR rec IN SELECT DISTINCT napfue, numreg, annee_ref FROM residentiel.tc_conso where numreg='74' AND annee_ref=2010 ORDER BY napfue, numreg, annee_ref LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'Analyse de la napfue % pour la région % de l''année %', rec.napfue, rec.numreg, rec.annee_ref;
    SELECT sum(conso) FROM general.vue_declarations_consommations WHERE numreg=rec.numreg AND annee_ref=rec.annee_ref AND niveau='region' AND napfue=rec.napfue AND snap=res_snap INTO total_reg;
    FOR rec2 IN SELECT DISTINCT ordre, niveau FROM general.vue_declarations_consommations WHERE numreg=rec.numreg AND annee_ref=rec.annee_ref AND napfue=rec.napfue AND snap=res_snap ORDER BY ordre ASC LOOP
      RAISE NOTICE '  Analyse du niveau %', rec2.niveau;
      SELECT sum(conso) FROM general.vue_declarations_consommations WHERE numreg=rec.numreg AND annee_ref=rec.annee_ref AND niveau=rec2.niveau AND napfue=rec.napfue AND snap=res_snap INTO total_niv;
      RAISE NOTICE '    Total régional % || Total niveau %: %', total_reg, rec2.niveau, total_niv;
      IF round(total_niv::NUMERIC, 2) <> round(total_reg::NUMERIC, 2) THEN
        RAISE NOTICE '    Le total du niveau % est différent du total régional. Veuillez corriger pour que ce niveau soit pris en compte', rec2.niveau;
        CONTINUE;
      ELSE
        WITH ratio AS (
          SELECT
            tc.numreg,
            com.numdep,
            tc.numcom,
            tc.numiris,
            CASE rec2.niveau
              WHEN 'commune'::TEXT THEN
                sum(tc.conso_climat_reel)/sum(sum(tc.conso_climat_reel)) OVER (PARTITION BY tc.numcom)
              WHEN 'departement'::TEXT THEN
                sum(tc.conso_climat_reel)/sum(sum(tc.conso_climat_reel)) OVER (PARTITION BY com.numdep)
              WHEN 'region'::TEXT THEN
                sum(tc.conso_climat_reel)/sum(sum(tc.conso_climat_reel)) OVER (PARTITION BY tc.numreg)
              WHEN 'iris'::TEXT THEN
                1
            END AS ratio,
            tc.annee_ref,
            tc.achl,
            tc.catl,
            tc.napfue,
            tc.usage,
            tc.chfl,
            tc.typl,
            tc.type_equipement,
            tc.modele_equipement
          FROM residentiel.tc_conso tc
          INNER JOIN general.commune com ON (tc.annee_ref=com.annee_ref::INTEGER AND tc.numcom=com.numcom)
          WHERE tc.napfue=rec.napfue AND tc.numreg=rec.numreg AND tc.annee_ref=rec.annee_ref
          GROUP BY tc.numreg, com.numdep, tc.numcom, tc.annee_ref, tc.achl, tc.catl, tc.napfue, tc.usage,
            tc.chfl, tc.typl, tc.numiris, tc.type_equipement, tc.modele_equipement
        )

        INSERT INTO residentiel.tc_conso_corrigees
        (numreg, numcom, numiris, conso, annee_ref, achl, catl, napfue, usage, chfl, typl, type_equipement, modele_equipement)  (
          SELECT
            r.numreg,
            r.numcom,
            r.numiris,
            dci.conso*r.ratio,
            r.annee_ref,
            r.achl,
            r.catl,
            r.napfue,
            r.usage,
            r.chfl,
            r.typl,
            r.type_equipement,
            r.modele_equipement
          FROM ratio r
          INNER JOIN residentiel.vue3_declarations_consos_020200_iris dci USING (annee_ref, numiris, napfue)
          WHERE dci.numreg=rec.numreg AND dci.annee_ref=rec.annee_ref AND dci.niveau=rec2.niveau AND dci.napfue=rec.napfue
        );
        EXIT;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;

  RAISE NOTICE 'Remplissage de la table tc_conso_corrigees : OK';
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```